# Error #1069: Property marshall not found on field when marshall is a function name not property?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I'm getting the error, "Error #1069: Property marshall not found on field " when calling a function on an object. Also I'm pretty sure it worked before (haven't opened the project in a few months). It doesn't make sense because the function exists:

On SQLColumn.as:

```
public function marshall():String {
    var request:String = name;

    //... 

    return request;
}
```

And the code that has the error (in another class):

```
var field:SQLColumn; // value object class with one function (shown above)

for (var i:int;i<fieldsLength;i++) {
    field = fields[i];
    if (i>0) request += ",";
    request += " " + field.marshall(); // error here- the debugger doesn't even step into the function and the compiler has no problems at compile time
}
```

Also, I changed the function to be a static method on the SQLColumn class and pass in the column field and that *does* work.

```
public static function marshall(column:SQLColumn):String {
    var request:String = column.name;

    //... 

    return request;
}
```

In another class,

```
request += " " + SQLColumn.marshall(field); // works
```

~~**UPDATE**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

SO after I changed it to static and it worked then I changed it back to what it was before and now it's working... No runtime error.

Comment: Sounds like something got cached when you compiled the first time.  You may want to delete this question since it's not really going to be helpful to anyone later.

Comment: Yeah. I ran clean a few times and that usually fixes issues like this but it didn't this time. Changing the code and then reverted did it. I think Eclipse cached something (like you suggested). I wouldn't assume it won't be helpful. If it happened to me it could happen to someone else. Now there's a record of it. And most likely if I put down the project and pick it up a year from now and it happens again I will probably remember but if I don't I have this question to return to.